# class does not contain a definition for function

Tags: c#, function, class, generics, inheritance

I have a bunch of classes that all extend one specific base class see below:

```
public class UIBaseProperties
{

}

public class EasyRawImage : UIBaseProperties
{
    public void SetImageDimensions(float? width = null, float? height = null)
    {
        if(width == null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Img.width, Img.height);
        else if(width != null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)width/Img.width*Img.height);
        else if(width == null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)height/Img.height*Img.width, (float)height);
        else if(width != null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)height);
    }
}
```

Now i have in an other class a list of UIBaseProperties to which i add different instances that all derive from UIBaseProperties like so:

```
public class OpenRecordUI
{
    private List<UIBaseProperties> UIElements;

    public OpenRecordUI()
    {
        UIElements = new List<UIBaseProperties>();
        UIElements.Add(new EasyRawImage(Resources.Load("Images/" + Data.local_photo_name), new Vector2(50, 50), v.GetActualPixelSizes().size.x, v.GetActualPixelSizes().size.y));
        var test = UIElements[0].SetImageDimensions(); // error
    }
}
```

Now i get the error when i try to call the SetImageDimensions() function. The error i get is the following:

> 'UIBaseProperties' does not contain a definition for 'SetImageDimensions' and no extension method 'SetImageDimensions'

I get why i get the error but i dont know how to do this any other way.
Is this even possible or else how should it be done?

If anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: `SetImageDimensions` only belongs to `EasyRawImage`

Comment: @Nkosi yes i know but my question is: "is there a way to acces "`SetImageDimensions` from the base class?"

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want to do here - if you want a list of things that you can call `SetImageDimensions` on, then you need a `List<EasyRawImage>`. As a general rule, if you have multiple classes that need to be interacted with differently, then you shouldn't try to treat them as being the same thing.

Comment: @FutureCake This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @FutureCake from what you've posted, it's not clear why you need a base class, or even a list. It's clear you've made some design mistakes but without knowing more it's impossible to suggest improvements that aren't just poor workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare `UIBaseProperties` as an `abstract` class and `SetImageDimensions` as an `abstract` method. Then at each derived class from `UIBaseProperties` you should provide an implementation for this method.

```
public abstract class UIBaseProperties
{
    public abstract SetImageDimensions(float? width = null, float? height = null);
}
```

Then by overriding the `SetImageDimensions`, the error would not exist any more.

```
public class EasyRawImage : UIBaseProperties
{
    public override void SetImageDimensions(float? width = null, float? height = null)
    {
        if(width == null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Img.width, Img.height);
        else if(width != null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)width/Img.width*Img.height);
        else if(width == null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)height/Img.height*Img.width, (float)height);
        else if(width != null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)height);
    }
}
```

Another approach it would be to avoid inheritance (define a base class, then derive from it etc.). You could have the same result by declaring an interface and then each class you have mentioned to implement this interface:

```
// The name of the interface is not very good, you should probably 
// think for another name.
public interface IUIBaseProperties
{
    void SetImageDimensions(float? width = null, float? height = null)
}
```

Then re-declare your class as below:

```
public class EasyRawImage : IUIBaseProperties
{
    public void SetImageDimensions(float? width = null, float? height = null)
    {
        if(width == null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Img.width, Img.height);
        else if(width != null && height == null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)width/Img.width*Img.height);
        else if(width == null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)height/Img.height*Img.width, (float)height);
        else if(width != null && height != null)
            RectOptions.sizeDelta = new Vector2((float)width, (float)height);
    }
}
```

and use it as below:

```
public class OpenRecordUI
{
    private List<IUIBaseProperties> UIElements;

    public OpenRecordUI()
    {
        UIElements = new List<IUIBaseProperties>();
        UIElements.Add(new EasyRawImage(Resources.Load("Images/" + Data.local_photo_name), new Vector2(50, 50), v.GetActualPixelSizes().size.x, v.GetActualPixelSizes().size.y));
        var test = UIElements[0].SetImageDimensions();
    }
}
```

Comment: @FutureCake not a problem :) . I have just edited my answer.

Comment: @FutureCake Thanks, hope the answer that is helpful !

Comment: Yeah it definitly is!

Comment: @Nkosi nice comment ! I would edit the answer again. Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi or better yet make the base implementation a no-op and just override it where you need to... this still feels a bit off to me, though, since `SetImageProperties` is presumably meaningless to most types of `UIBaseProperties` - I would generally prefer to apply this explicitly to the `EasyRawImage`s before they are mixed into the generalised collection... hard to do much better with the context provided though.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. The class `UIBaseProperties` does not have a method `SetImageDimensions`.

When you create a List containing objects of a specific type, they are all treated as being of exactly that type. Sure, you can store instances of classes that inherit from the one in the definition in there, but they are still treated as instances of the parent class.

In your case, everything in your list is treated as an instance of `UIBaseProperties`, even though they are instances of the child class `EasyRawImage`. Since the parent class does not have the method `SetImageDimensions`, you cannot access it, even though your objects actually do contain it.

To get around this, you need to cast each object back to the child type when you access it, like so:

```
((EasyRawImage)UIElements[0]).SetImageDimensions();
```

This however is considered poor practice. It would be preferable to not define the list as containing `UIBaseProperties` objects in the first place. Instead, use something like an abstract class, or an interface pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that `UIElements[0]` is of type `UIBaseProperties`.

If the `UIElements` collection can only contain things of type `EasyRawImage`, then it should be typed as `List<EasyRawImage>`, then you would be able to call that method with the line you already have.

However, if you intend to put other implementations of that base class in the collection, then you need to leave the declaration as it is; but you need to be sure that the item is of that type before you use it. Rather than casting it, with `((EasyRawImage)UIElements[0])` (which will fail if it is not that type) you can do this:

```
var test = UIElements[0] asEasyRawImage;
if (test != null)
{
    test.SetImageDimensions();
}
```